# How to Import objects

Tags: python, django, sqlite, import

I use `populate_core.py` script to populate my sqlite database:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'projectname.settings')

import django
django.setup()

from core.models import *

def populate():
    north = add_region('North')
    south = add_region('South')

def add_region(name):
    r = Region.objects.get_or_create(name=name)[0]
    r.save()
    return r

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ("Starting Core population script...")
    populate()
```

Then I want to use `populate_main.py` script to add some data to the database:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'projectname.settings')

import django
django.setup()

from core.models import *
from populate_core import *

def populate1():
    dist_one = add_district('Dist_one', north)

def add_district(name, region):
    d = District.objects.get_or_create(name=name, region=region)[0]
    d.save()
    return d

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ("Starting main population script...")
    populate1()
```

Both the scripts are in the project main directory (where is manage.py). When i run the first script it works but when I run the second scripts it give an error:

```
NameError: name 'north' is not defined
```

I think to be doing something wrong on the import line.

As alternative the 'north' object is in the database (db.sqlite3) so maybe I should look there?

Thank you for your help

Comment: north and south are variables within a function so they are out of scope for your import. You can move their definition outside of the function but they still won't have a value unless you run `populate`

Comment: So i should duplicate all the variables (inside and outside the function)? that's too long... What about using the database? in the database there are north and south (after i run populate_core.py)

Comment: I'm not sure why you need two separate commands in the first place, if one relies on the other then why not just have one do both?

Comment: I could use one unique and it will works but some data is fixed, some is variable from project to project, so using two scripts I have only to change the second. Maybe is easier and cleaner, don't you think? Also they are some thousand of line long so maybe is better to keep them separated. Anyway I accept advice on this